# how to use images plus repeating background in <h1>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an `<h1>` that has text centered, an image on each side, and then dynamically fill in lines to the remaining width of the container.

I've tried a few techniques... currently using :before and :after, with a nested span. :after is working, but trying to solve the :before part.

Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/dtar4rgs/](http://jsfiddle.net/dtar4rgs/)

Comment: don't do it that way. do something more like `<h1><span id="before"></span>Heading<span id="after"></span</h1>`. CSS is useful, but its abilities to "insert" things into the dom is very limited - it's for FORMATTING, not for faking/replacing actual content/markup.

Comment: your code is working in FF, but Marc B is correct, do it the proper way unless there's no other way to do it (like styling some page you don't have access to the html code)

Comment: Your fiddle appears to be displaying properly. I would agree with @MarcB however.

Comment: Depending on the browsers you have to support... http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/dtar4rgs/3/

Comment: @Fabio if you edit the text in the heading you'll see it's not dynamic.

Comment: @bfrohs that looks like an answer, thanks. I hadn't thought of flex...  Maybe I'll just omit the lines if IE < 10 (or js fallback).

Comment: with @bfrohs answer, http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ for cross browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to achieve what you're looking to do ([demo (supports flexbox)](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/dtar4rgs/11/), [demo (doesn't support flexbox)](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/dtar4rgs/12/)):

```html
<div id="container">
    <h1><span>a b c</span></h1>
    <p>Change text shorter or longer.</p>
    <p>Need left lines to be dynamic.</p>
</div>
```

```
h1 {
    display:flex; /* Treats the :before, :after, and span as individual items */
    align-items:center; /* Aligns items vertically (to align border properly) */
    text-align:center; /* Aligns items horizontally for browsers that don't support flexbox */
}
h1 span {
    /* Places arrow on each side of span */
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101534624/arrow_cyan.gif') no-repeat left,
    url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101534624/arrow_cyan.gif') no-repeat right;
    padding: 0 50px; /* Prevents text from overlapping image */
}
h1:before,
h1:after {
    content: " ";
    /* Lines on sides of header */
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101534624/h1-lines.png') repeat-x;
    height: 6px; /* Height of lines */
    flex-grow:1; /* Makes lines expand to edges of screen */
}
```

**Note:** [Support for flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is lacking (IE11+), but with `text-align:center`, the only difference is the lack of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well this get's you part way. I'm not sure what it is you want with the two `<p>` elements but I will say that it's 100% bad practice and non-symantec to put them in a `<h*>`.

Here's the code: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtar4rgs/2/)

I've put another nested span in there to give you the white buffer you need, this won't work with a background image very well. So it may not be exactly what you're looking for. This allows your `<h1>` to be any text length.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1><span><span>Heading</span></span></h1>
</div>
<p>Change text shorter or longer.</p>
<p>Need left lines to be dynamic.</p>
```

CSS:

```
 #container {
    width: 1000px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101534624/h1-lines.png') repeat-x center;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 span {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
h1 span > span {
    background: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101534624/arrow_cyan.gif') no-repeat left, url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101534624/arrow_cyan.gif') no-repeat right;
    padding: 0 50px;
}
```

Comment: This would work, except that I can't have the span background be white. It needs to be transparent because of an underlying graphic. The p elements are just instructions. They aren't nested in h1.

Comment: Ah, they were nested in it in your original fiddle. Bit confusing there. I'm afraid there isn't a way to really do what you're attempting with simple CSS (that I know of anyway). You could make the heading have a standard bg separate from the rest of the page, so it appears as a block of its own. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/dtar4rgs/4/

Comment: Only other option is the `flex` one mentioned in comments above. Which is both better and nifty. This however is the only fully cross-browser compatible version.